# Запретить доступ к .js файлам

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Здравствуйте можно ли с помощью Apache запретить доступ к .js файлам пробовал так но не получилось

```
 RewriteRule !\. (js|gif|png|css)$ index.php
```

Comment: Если запретить их апачем, в браузер они тоже грузиться не будут. Вы уверены, что хотите этого?

Comment: Когда клиент откроет вашу страницу в браузере - он может сохранить ее содержимое, включая и js файлы.

Comment: Даже если сделать fortribben на все js файлы?О_о<br>
нуну...

Comment: спасибо большое, а ввобще это както реализовать можно?

Answer (score 0):

Если запретить отдачу js сервером, то и на странице скрипты работать не будут. Поэтому попробуем их спрятать от большинства пользователей хитростью.
Этот способ основан на том, что когда браузер загружает скрипт со страницы он выставляет заголовок HTTP_REFFER, а когда вбиваешь адрес в адресную строку или нажимаешь просмотр кода страницы, то он этот заголовок не выставляет.
Соответственно будем выдавать два разных скрипта в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия этого заголовка (а точнее три).
И соответственно обходится этот способ передачей вместе с прямым url на js еще и заголовка HTTP_REFERER.
Тестировал в 4-ех браузерах: хром, файрфокс, опера, ослик. Все браузеры последних версий. Полет нормальный.
Для того, чтобы мало у кого возникло желание копаться в поисках настоящего скрипта надо сделать фиктивный скрипт максимально реалистичным, запутанным и сложным, тогда человек погрузится в его разбор и наверное сдастся в итоге понять принцип работы сайта :)
Итак, наша цель скрыть скрипт на страницу nojs.php

```
<? header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8'); echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>alpha</title></head><body><DIV class="root">
Сейчас Вы должны увидеть работу настоящего скрипта в виде аллерта <A href="javascript:deadoralive();">нажмите ссылку после алерта, дабы убедиться что события тоже не отвалились.</A>
</DIV><DIV id="fictive" style="display:none">666</DIV></body><script src="test.php"></script></html>

?>
```

test.php

```
<?
header('Content-Type:text/javascript;charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 
    echo 'var div1=document.getElementById("fictive"); var sc=document.createElement("script"); sc.src="test2.php"; div1.appendChild(sc); window.setTimeout("div1.removeChild(sc);", 5000); window.setTimeout("deadoralive();", 10000);';
} else {
    echo 'alert("Я фиктивный скрипт 1 :)");';
};
?>
```

test2.php

```
<?
header('Content-Type:text/javascript;charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    echo 'function deadoralive() {alert("Я живой");};';
} else {
    echo 'alert("Я фиктивный скрипт 2 :)");';
};
?>
```

[все одним архивом](http://db.tt/fQbUJrXh)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так в настройках виртуальных хостов или в .htaccess

```
<Files ~ "\.js$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```